# Render passes composite doesn’t match beauty

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

i am using nuke for compositing render passes from blender. but when i combined it in nuke, render pesses composite from blender looks different from beauty. i have followed the nodes formula according to blender
[image]

i also test for simple scene using mesh from blender.

[image]

Comment: any viewport color transforms causing this? have you compared the images in nuke to verfiy the mismatch?

Comment: i tried to compare passes diffuse and gloss 1 by 1 every passes, and there is a slightly different between nuke and blender. 
Are the color management of blender and nuke really different? i am using srgb in nuke and standard in blender for color management. thanks.

Comment: well, how differently they behave is really a question of how you manage it in either software. In Nuke you have different options reading your source material but also various options on displaying and writing it. With blender it is exactly the same. That's why I was asking whether you actually can measure a color difference between the combined pass rendered from blender and the combined pass merged in nuke if you compare the the color values. If they are the same I think it is an issue of setting up the color management properly - if not, you should be thinking of filing a bug report.

Comment: classic color workflow for CG should be linear